# PrintedPdfDocument bmp to pdf

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to save a bmp image to pdf:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

try {

        scannedImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        // open a new document
        PrintedPdfDocument document = new PrintedPdfDocument(context, bitmap); // cannot resolve symbol context.

        // start a page
        PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(0);

        // draw something on the page
        View content = scannedImageView;
        content.draw(page.getCanvas());

        // finish the page
        document.finishPage(page);
        // add more pages

        // write the document content
        document.writeTo(getOutputStream()); // cannot resolve method getOutputStream()

        //close the document
        document.close();
}
```

I have commented erros in `context` and `getOutputStream()`. Any ideas how to solve?

Comment: Where are the errors?

Answer (score 0):

- If you are using `Activity` class you should replace `context` with `this`.
- If you are using `Fragment` class you should replace `context` with `getContext()`.
- If you are using `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` you should be able to use `requireContext()` as it makes sure you will receive `Context` object or it will throw an exception.

Here are the declarations of `getContext()` and `requireContext()` methods in `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`:

[image]

`getOutputStream()` is not defined in `Activity` or `Fragment`. This is the function you should define that will return output stream that will define to which file your PDF will be written to. You may want to get a look at [FileOutputStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream).